# Проблема с классом Asset (cms Bitrix)

Tags: классы

Для подключения стилей, скриптов использую класс `Asset : use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;`
Затем произвожу подключения.

Файл `header.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
  <?php

use  Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;


?>
    <!--A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layout
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <head>
      <?php $APPLICATION->ShowHead() ?>
      <title>
        <?php $APPLICATION->ShowTitle() ?>
      </title>
      <?php


 Asset::getInctance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/css/style.css');
    Asset::getInctance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
    Asset::getInctance()->addString('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">');
     Asset::getInctance()->addString("<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monda' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
     Asset::getInctance()->addString("<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");    



?>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header_top">
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="header-top-left">
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                  <h1>SHARE</h1>
                  <h2>The Blog</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menu bounce">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="single.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="single.html">Support</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-top-right">
              <div class="social-icons">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="youtube" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Youtube</span></a></li>
                  <li><a class="facebook" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span> </a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Twitter</span> </a></li>
                  <li><a class="skype" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Skype</span> </a></li>
                  <li><a class="likedin" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Likedin</span> </a></li>
                  <li><a class="vimeo" href="#" target="_blank"><span>vimeo</span> </a></li>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="search_box">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" class="text-box" placeholder="Search for Blog"><input type="submit" value="" />
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--------------------- Main Content ------------------->
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="main">
          <div class="content">
```

В результате имею следующую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInctance()
in C:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix\local\templates\blog\header.php on line 21
```

Подскажите, почему так происходит? Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php

if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;
$asset = Asset::getInstance();
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?></title>
        <?$APPLICATION->ShowHead();?>
        <?
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/bootstrap.min.css");
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/slick.css");
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/slick-theme.css");
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/nouislider.min.css");
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/font-awesome.min.css");
        $asset->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/style.css");

        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/jquery.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/slick.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/nouislider.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/jquery.zoom.min.js');
        $asset->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/main.js');
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?>
```